# Why this program is not giving right outputs.(find lexographically smallest permutation of the set of Integers)

Tags: java, list, matrix, permutation, treeset

A permutation is a list of K numbers, each between 1 and K

(both inclusive), that has no duplicate elements.

Permutation X
is lexicographically smaller than Permutation Y if for some i≤K

:

All of the first i-1 elements of X are equal to first i-1 elements of Y.
ith element of X is smaller than ith element of Y.

You are given a permutation P
, you can exchange some of its elements as many times as you want in any order. You have to find the lexicographically smallest Permutation that you can obtain from P

.

K
is less than 101

.

Input Format:
First line of input contains K
being the size of permutation.
Next line contains K single spaced numbers indicating the permutation.
Each of next K lines contains K characters, character j of line i is equal to 'Y' if you can exchange ith and jth element of a permutation, and 'N

' otherwise.

Output Format:
Print K

numbers with a space separating each of them indicating the permutation.
SAMPLE INPUT

3
3 2 1
NYN
YNY
NYN

SAMPLE OUTPUT

1 2 3

Explanation

first can be exchanged with second. So, from 3
2 1 , we can get 2 3 1. 2 3 1 is lexicographically smaller than 3 2 1. Matrix also says the second the third element can be swapped. From this we get, 2 1 3. 2 1 3 is lexicographically smaller than 2 3 1. As the matrix says the first and the second element can be swapped, we get 1 2 3 from 2 1 3 and hence the answer 1 2 3.

My Code is:

```
import java.util.*;

class arperm {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        TreeSet<String> tr=new TreeSet<String>();
      int t=sc.nextInt();int ar[]=new int[t];String as[]=new String[t];
      for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
         ar[i]=sc.nextInt(); 
      }
       for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
         as[i]=sc.nextLine().trim(); 
      }
       for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<as[i].length();j++){
           if(as[i].charAt(j)=='Y'){
             // StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(as[i]); 
               int temp=ar[i];
               ar[i]=ar[j];
               ar[j]=temp;
           }  
           String s="";
           for(int ii:ar){
               s+=Integer.toString(ii)+" ";
           }
           tr.add(s.trim());
         System.out.println(tr.first());
         } 


       }
     //  for(String ss:tr)
      // System.out.print(tr.first());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? and what is the wrong output you are getting? for what input?

Comment: It is a question from Hacker earth. It is giving right outputs for the given input but for other inputs is is giving wrong output.You can check all the element of the tree set by printing that i think by checking all the elements of tree Set you can find errors.